# How to use BG Fuel Injection System Cleaner?

Tags: engine, cleaning, fuel-system, fuel-tank

Recently, after a periodic servicing visit for my car (which has a multi point fuel injection system), the mechanic handed me BG Fuel Injection System Cleaner Part No. 210 and asked me to put it in the car engine after filling the tank half full. I am not sure as to wether to put the cleaner fluid in the Gas Tank or the Oil Filter. 
BG's own site states that "This product is designed to be used with the BG 9210 Inject-A-Flush® Apparatus and BG 44K® Part No. 208." I neither have the BG 9210 apparatus nor the BG44k. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I would not put that product in the tank. It is designed to be used full strength. The BG 9210 Inject-A-Flush® is used to pressurize the fuel system and let the car run directly off the cleaner. The 44K is used in the tank after the 210 has been run through the injectors.